# NSLayoutConstraint problen

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

```
//MARK: NSLayoutConstraints
//trailing
let trailingConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:imageView.superview , attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
trailingConstaint.isActive = true

//leading
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
leadingConstraint.isActive = true

//top
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
topConstraint.isActive = true

//bottom
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
bottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

I wanted to resize the image so that it fits so that the image is scaled properly
[screenshot of ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYMBb.jpg)

But i get this error..

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for
>    size {746, 496} orientation 0 scale
>   1.000000: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.'

Comment: must define constraints between views which are subviews of a same view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//top
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
topConstraint.isActive = true
```

You are setting this constraint to the **image** instead of **imageView**.

The exception clearly states that `Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or UILayoutGuide.'`

All the other constraints are set between **imageView** and **imageView.superView**, so logically the above constraint should also use the same pair.

This will take care of the exception.

```
//top
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
topConstraint.isActive = true
```

But, Image scaling cannot be achieved by constraints. You have to set the **contentMode** property appropriately. Check **Understanding How Images Are Scaled** section in the [well-explained docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview)

Comment: Yes, i had to just replace image with imageView.A silly mistake from my side. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I actually was trying to replace the old constraints of a placeholder with a new image selected from the photoLibrary.

Comment: You don't need to change the constraints when you change the content. The image will be resiZed according to the `contentMode` and the existing constraints.

Comment: But, as @Paulw11 has suggested in his answer, I also insist that it is better to place your constraints in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have referenced a **image** instead of **imageView** in your topConstraint. 
It’s hard to tell for sure without seeing a bit more of your code but try updating that and see if it works.

```
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.superview, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
topConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem a silly mistake from my side.Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your third constraint you have used `image` instead of `imageView`. You can't set constraints on an image, only on views.  Look at how you are setting `imageView`.

Is there a reason why you aren't simply setting the constraints in Interface Builder?  They are quite straight-forward.

You can set the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView` to determine how the image is scaled.  `scaleAspectFill` is typically what you want, although this will result in some cropping of the image if it doesn't precisely fit the view.  `scaleAspectFit` will ensure that the entire image is shown, but some padding will be required if the image size doesn't match the view size.  `scaleToFill` will fill the view without padding, potentially at the cost of distorting the image.

Comment: I actually have an image in the imageView as a placeholder with constraints.But I'm selecting an image from photo library and giving it new constraints to replace previous ones.Thank you for helping out.